# 20K products using autocompletion, want to build static javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Instead of me hitting the database each time someone types a character into the search box, I want to create static .js files.

What are some techniques I can use to create static .js files that are basically arrays to load the jquery autocomplete plugin with.

My product sku's look like:

```
ABC1234
```

or

```
Alpha Beta C 1234
```

(abc is the short form for the manufacturer name, while 'Alpha Beta C' is the long form, followed by 3-4 numbers).

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use for JSON.  Javascript Object Notation.  You can just include the JS files and you'll have all your data in objects.

http://www.json.org

```
var products = [{sku:'aaaa', price: 50}, {sku:'bbbb', price: 60}];
```

Please check my syntax, it's from memory.

Comment: Depending on bandwidth constraints and the length of each product name, that first page load could be a doozey.

Comment: I would definitely make sure that the js script loader is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That's true.  What you might want to do is put the JSON file on the back end of an AJAX call.  That way you're not loading the whole database in the page at runtime and you're not hitting the db each time either.  This would work unless your product database is constantly updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send all remaining possibilities in JSON via an AJAX call only **after** 2/3 keystrokes and extract the remaining results from that object/array (I don't know if JQuery supports this behaviour). This saves bandwidth, as not your whole database has to be sent to the client, and you don't have to call the database more than once (generally, if the first keys were correct).

I am not sure if your question is also server-side related (nor what server-side technology you use), so just FYI, have a look at [PHP's JSON functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) (especially [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) to read more about it.

Comment: Yeah, sending a JS quasi-database to the client sounds painful

Answer (score 0):

You could build a minimised finite state machine (e.g. a DAWG) which contains final nodes for all of your product codes that exist. Then store this in some optimised format in a Javascript string (or a smallish number of strings).

These strings could then be sent compressed to the browser, it would probably not take very long to load.

Then you can traverse the state machine depending on the number of characters already typed in and efficiently find all product codes which start with those characters.

That's how I'd do it anyway.

Or may be just load the whole dictionary because 20k isn't that many. I wrote a Javascript game which loaded a dictionary bigger than that and wasn't a real problem.

Comment: He says 20K *products*, not 20K bytes. If one product record is represented by 100 bytes of JSON, you'll have to download 2 MB of JSON data to get the whole database.

Comment: Just to store the product code though, should not take 100 bytes, and significantly less if you store them efficiently and compress it. I think 10 bytes is more realistic.